# How to make a some button on web form with Action Script

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am absolute beginner in Flash, and AS3.
I need to make dynamically some amount of buttons in web page. I must use Action Script and MXML.
If It will be PHP I will call echo function.

So help me please.

Comment: If all you need are some buttons, you need not go for Flash or Flex; just use html `<input type="button" onclick="alert('tadaaa');" value="click me"/>` Start by reading some html tutorial. Use javascript (and/or some framework like jQuery) to add buttons dynamically

Comment: thank you for advice. But I need to do it using AS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS you can use the class [RemoteObject](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/flex_remoteobject/) (example with amfphp) to communicate with the server. Then you can send an Xml or anything else to describe your GUI.

In actionscript you can add components to container like this:

```
    var horizontalContainer:HBox = new HBox();
    horizontalContainer.percentWidth = 100;
    addChild(horizontalContainer);  
    var btn:Button = new Button();
    horizontalContainer.addChild(btn);
    btn.label = "Click me !";
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClickHandler);
    private function btnClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
            // Do what you want
    }
```

You can do a loop to add multiple buttons.
HBox is the layout of the container. You have multiple type of layouts in Flex. I advise you to do a lot of tutorial to learn the basics of Flex.